# Input autocomplete problem with unicode characters

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, autocomplete

I am using latest version of Google Chrome in windows 7. Input fields with autocomplete property, not showing Farsi characters but empty squares however English charactres are being dispayed correctly. Should I solve this problem using html or css codes or this is a systematic bug?

Image description:

[image]

Comment: It'll be good if you can post the code you are trying?

Comment: it happens for all input fields which have not `autocomplete="off"` @AbhinawKaushik

Comment: looks like something to do with page `Encoding`